# How does grid view determine the columns when data-bound to IEnumerable<Something>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

While experimenting with SharePoint, I created a simplistic web part which displays the partitions and their respective sizes. Here's the relevant code:

**ASCX file:**

```
[...]
<asp:GridView ID="diskSpaceReport" runat="server" DataSource="<%# Partitions %>">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Used" HeaderText="Used" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected IEnumerable<Partition> Partitions
{
    get
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<Partition>>() != null);

        return from drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
               let usedSpace = drive.IsReady ?
                   drive.TotalFreeSpace * 100 / drive.TotalSize : 0
               select new Partition(drive.Name, usedSpace);
    }
}
```

**Partition.cs:**

```
[...]
public string Name { get { ... } }
public Percentage Used { get { ... } }
[...]
```

Those are **the only two properties** of the class.

### Problem

The grid view displays three columns:

- The name,
- The used space percentage,
- The name, once again.

In order to hide the third column, I have to add `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` to `<asp:GridView>` block. If I remove the `<Columns>` block, the grid view displays only one column—the name (previously the third column).

### Question

I don't understand how the grid view auto-generates the columns. I imagine that it works well when the grid view is bound to an SQL table or similar data elements, but it obviously fails when bound to an enumeration of custom objects.

How it achieved to find `Name` property, but failed to understand that `Used` should be displayed as well?

Comment: Is Percentage a custom class? Do it have a tostring() implementation

Comment: Only properties that return one of a handful of fixed types (string, dates, integers, etc.) are bound using `AutoGenerateColumns`.  Your custom type, not being one of them, isn't bound automatically.

Comment: @XtremeBytes: indeed, `Percentage` is a custom class. It overrides `ToString()`.

Comment: @Servy: can you post this as an answer, eventually specifying the types which can be used?

Comment: @MainMa I would if I could find any official documentation on it; as it is I could only find personal blogs that state it.  The documentation *says* that all properties are bound (which is clearly false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine the source code for the default automatic column generator [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/GridViewColumnsGenerator.cs,10).

On a quick read-through it looks like `Public`, `Instance` `properties` that `IsBindableType` returns true for.
`IsBindableType` source is available [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/DataBoundControlHelper.cs,6d1e7faa31d5f732).  It includes primitive types (int, string, dates, etc), as well as types marked with `BindableAttribute`.

The key bit of code from source that determines if a column is generated is this bit here:

```
            if (type.IsPrimitive ||
                   (type == typeof(string)) ||
                   (type == typeof(DateTime)) ||
                   (type == typeof(Decimal)) ||
                   (type == typeof(Guid)) ||
                // support for new SqlServer 2008 types:
                   (type == typeof(DateTimeOffset)) ||
                   (type == typeof(TimeSpan))) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                BindableTypeAttribute bindableTypeAttribute = (BindableTypeAttribute)TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(type)[typeof(BindableTypeAttribute)];
                if (bindableTypeAttribute != null) {
                    return bindableTypeAttribute.IsBindable;
                }
                else {
                    //We consider enums as Bindable types by default but provide an opt-out mechanism using BindableTypeAttribute. (Ex : EntityState)
                    //So the order of above if-else block is important.
                    return (enableEnums && type.IsEnum);
                }
            }
```